# How to upload to imagefield in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I can create my objects in Django Framework and upload images directly from there.
Now I want to upload image from an HTML form and no more from Django Framework. How can i upload image from my HTML to my `/media/` folder?

my models.py:

```
class New(models.Model):
news_title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,verbose_name="Titolo news")
news_small_description = models.TextField(default=None,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Descrizione breve")
news_description = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Descrizione")
news_image = models.ImageField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Immagine")
news_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, verbose_name="Data news")
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "New"
    verbose_name_plural = "News"
```

my view.py POST API:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_news(request):
    try:
        newstitle = get_param(request.POST, "newstitle", NOT_NONE)
        newssmalldescription = get_param(request.POST, "newssmalldescription", OPTIONAL)
        newsdescription = get_param(request.POST, "newsdescription", OPTIONAL)
        newsimage = get_param(request.POST, "newsimage", OPTIONAL)

        New.objects.create(
            news_title = newstitle,
            news_small_description = newssmalldescription,
            news_description = newsdescription,
            news_image = newsimage,
        )

        return HttpResponse("La tua novità è stata aggiunta correttamente.")

    except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve)
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps({"error_message": str(ve)}), content_type='application/json')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({"error_message": str(e)}), content_type="application/json")
```

In my html i send a POST request to my `send_news` API and the only missing field is the `newsimage`.
But i can't understand how can i charge a pic from my HTML page to my MEDIA folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `request.FILES` instead of `request.POST` while working with files:
`newsimage = get_param(request.FILES, "newsimage", OPTIONAL)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. But how can I SEND my image to the api function from the html?

Comment: Did u try to add your api-url to the form `action` in html? I think you need to play around that.

Comment: Also looks like your form also need to have set attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, like said here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Comment: I get 'Request' object has no attribute 'FILE' using request.FILES.. ideas?

Comment: Do u upload an image at the same time? If not - it will throw error (not having this error I usually use `request.FILES.get("myfile")` -  it returns None instead of error). If yes - seems like u have wrong configured your html form.

Comment: Yes i upload a single image. Using newsimage = get_param(request.POST, "newsimage", OPTIONAL) i get the file name uploaded and the object created but the IMAGE is not uploaded in the MEDIA folder

Comment: Did u add MEDIA_ROOT to your urls?

Comment: Did you also had `encrypt` in your form, as you asked in another question, in our discussion?

Comment: This was the problem I just solved . Thanks however best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you made your form enctype="multypart/form-data"?

```
 <form class="col" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"action="{% url 'your_action' %}">
```

I had the same problem